# how can I pass array from drupal code to js file

Tags: theming, javascript

I have an array define in my module and I want to pass that array value to js file according to that i want to add class to html.
.module file

```
$aha_initiatives = '#aha_initiatives';
  //Add a JS library
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'benefit_with_unite_tabs/quick-tab';
$variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['lotus']['lotusJS']['aha_initiatives'] = $aha_initiatives;
```

.js file

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {

Drupal.behaviors.benefit_with_unite_tabls = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // can access setting from 'drupalSettings';
    var aha_initiatives = drupalSettings.lotus.lotusJS.aha_initiatives;

     if(window.location.hash == aha_initiatives) {
        $(".tabbable #myTab ."+window.location.hash.substr(1)).addClass("active");
        $(".tabbable #myTabContent #"+window.location.hash.substr(1)).addClass("active in");
      }
  }
};
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

here iam sending single variable but i want to send array how can I do that

Comment: An array _is_ a single variable - pass it as you would any other, it’ll be available in your js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // In your form alter or block or controller or where ever you have this attached.
$array = [
  'red' => 'red so hot right now',
  'blue' => 'wow thats blue',
];
$form['#attached']['drupalSettings']['myArrayOfStuff'] = $array;
```

Then JS:

```
console.log(drupalSettings.myArrayOfStuff);
```